# rtorrent xml-rpc commands load torrent and get id of added torrent from nodejs

Tags: node.js, xml-rpc, torrent

I'm trying to load a torrent into an rtorrent client through nodejs. I'm using the plugin node-rtorrent, but i can edit it or use another one if needed.

So what i want to do is to add a torrent, etc. using the rtorrent.loadLink witch is using the rpc command load_start. However I don't know how to get the ID of the currently added torrent in order to track it.
sure i could just get a list before and a list after and the new item is properly the torrent that was just added. However i don't think this is good enough since i would properly at somepoint want to add multiple torrents at a time.

An alternative could be to tell it where to put the torrent and i could search on the path. but i don't know how to add a torrent and tell it where to put it at the same time.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming ID == infohash, you just calculate it from the metafile that you pass in.